# Weibull Kernel Density Estimation in R

Tags: r, kernel-density, density-plot

I am trying to evaluate the work of Salha et al. (2014), entitled as "*Hazard Rate Function Estimation Using Weibull Kernel*". But my density graph (**for real data**) is just a flat line rather then a proper density plot similar to article. Here is expected density,my R code and Weibull kernel. kindly help me to find out my mistake.

[image: Expected Density]
[image: Weibull Kernel]

**R code:**

```
k<-200
yy<-c(1,1,1,5,7,8,8,13,14,14,17,18,21,21,22,25,27,27,30,30,31,31,32,34,35,36,37,38,39,39,40,49,49,54,56,56,62,63,65,65,67,75,76,79,82,83,84,84,84,90,91,92,93,93,103,103,111,112,119,122,123,126,129,134,144,147,153,163,167,175,228,231,235,242,256,256,257,311,314,322,369,415,573,609,640,737)
y<-log(yy)
n<-length(yy)

 h<-0.79 * IQR(y) * length(y) ^ (-1/5)
 x <- seq(min(yy) + 0.05, max(yy), length = k)

 KWeibull <- matrix(rep(0, k * n), ncol = k)
 fhat <- rep(0, k)
###########weibull###########
for (j in 1:k) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
        fn <- gamma(1 + h)
        KWeibull[i, j] <- (fn/(h * x[i])) * ((yy[i] * fn)/x[i])^((1/h) - 1) * exp(-((yy[i] * 
            fn)/x[i])^(1/h))
    }
    fhat[j] <- 1/n * (sum(KWeibull[, j]))
}

plot(x,fhat, type = "l")
```

Comment: Why you voted it down? please explain the reason.

Comment: Can you add expected result? We don't know how the plot should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hope this helps:*

There are two issues needing to be addressed to attain the above plot:

1. **Use Logarithm**

Firstly (in the [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiTzr6h8a_dAhUNK1AKHTyTC-MQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffile.scirp.org%2Fpdf%2FOJS_2014093011110815.pdf&usg=AOvVaw37QJq67XJmkm-pbe0-qe4p) which you are referring to) they use the logarithm of the input data - I found this in section 5.2 of the paper --- **below is this fix:**

```
k<-200
yy<-c(1,1,1,5,7,8,8,13,14,14,17,18,21,21,22,25,27,27,30,30,31,31,32,34,35,36,37,38,39,39,40,49,49,54,56,56,62,63,65,65,67,75,76,79,82,83,84,84,84,90,91,92,93,93,103,103,111,112,119,122,123,126,129,134,144,147,153,163,167,175,228,231,235,242,256,256,257,311,314,322,369,415,573,609,640,737)
y<-log(yy)
n<-length(yy)

#h<-0.79 * IQR(y) * length(y) ^ (-1/5)
x <- seq(min(y) + 0.05, max(y), length = k)
h <- 0.480411

KWeibull <- matrix(rep(0, k * n), ncol = k)
fhat <- rep(0, k)
```

*Note the bandwidth (h) is hard coded to be equivalent to the research papers bandwidth, however this is not a crucial fix.*

2. **For loop Indexing**

The for loop - you are iterating over your yy (which I think is your time variable in the kernel density estimator) but your x random sample your are iterating over the same set each time. And also use y rather than yy as this is the logarithmic transformed data.

**See below fix: (This includes the Logarithm fix)**

```
###########weibull###########
for (j in 1:k) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    fn <- gamma(1 + h)
    KWeibull[i, j] <- (fn/(h * x[j])) * ((y[i] * fn)/x[j])^((1/h) - 1) * exp(-((y[i] * 
                                                                                   fn)/x[j])^(1/h))
  }
  fhat[j] <- 1/n * (sum(KWeibull[, j]))
}

plot(yy,KWeibull[,86], type = "l")
plot(x,fhat, type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: but these are not similar to required one. Even scale on x-axis and y-axis are totally different.

Comment: Sorry in the Q it is not clear with regards to the input data - found in the research paper the use of the log of yy

Comment: I just used the bandwidth (0.480411) which is stated in the paper to ensure the exact same results

Comment: Thats great :) ---  @Angel can you mark as the answer